# Как сделать планировщик заданий phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Нужно чтобы каждый день из таблицы `users`, в столбец `balance` снималось 5руб.

Если balance <= 4, то не снималось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В phpmyadmin надо прописать:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
Or
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;

CREATE EVENT changeBalance
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
UPDATE user SET balance = balance - 5 WHERE balance > 4;
```

Comment: Ошибка
Статический анализ:

Найдено 1 ошибок при анализе.

Отсутствует выражение. (near "ON" at position 29)
SQL запрос:

SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON

Ответ MySQL: Документация

#1227 - В доступе отказано. Вам нужны привилегии SUPER для этой операции

Comment: @Phphelppls ну я вам права выдать дистанционно не могу)